# Is there something like Single.empty()

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm in the process of migrating from Rx 1 to Rx 2 and suddenly while reading through posts I found out that [Single](http://reactivex.io/documentation/single.html) should be the type of observable to use for retrofit calls.

So I've decided to give it a shot and while migrating our retrofit calls to Rx 2 I also changed the return value to `Single<whatever>`.

Now the issue is, some of our tests mock the network services something similar to:

```
when(userService.logout()).thenReturn(Observable.empty())
```

As you can see prior to migrating the calls we used to simply complete the stream by telling the `userService` mock to return an empty observable.

While migrating to the `Single` "version" of the calls we no longer can use `Observable.empty()` because the call doesn't return an `Observable`, but returns a `Single`.

I've ended up doing something like:

```
when(userService.logout()).thenReturn(
                    Single.fromObservable(Observable.<whatever>empty()))
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a better way of doing this?
2. Am I missing anything important that I should know - something like this actually doesn't behave as I'm expecting it to.

Comment: There is `ignoreElement()` on Single. This basically converts a Single to Completable. Not solution for this case, but in one of my scenario, this avoided the need for Single.empty() for me.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`Single.empty()` makes no sense because `Single` has to have a single item or an error. You could just have kept `Observable` or switched to `Maybe` which does allow empty or `Completable` which doesn't emit an item at all.

Answer (score 13):

A workaround e.g. for tests would be

`Observable.<Whatever>empty().toSingle()`

keep in mind that this does not call the subscribers at all.

Comment: I think this should be correct, with an explanation of what @akarnokd says.
For me, it was useful to mock a Single and not worrying about the rest.

Comment: Is this right? I'm new to kotlin but butting the generics in that position shows an error and toSingle doesn't seem to exist. Is there an updated version of this?

Is Single.just(0) cheaper?

Comment: use `Single.fromObservable()`